# Позиционирование картинки

Tags: html, css

Как мне картинку прибить к правому краю без увеличения ширины секции?Рука обрезалась чтобы к концу секции, получается, что размер картинки хоть и без фона но большой и дает мне скролл снизу и все ломается. Нужно прижать к правому краю до конца.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Добавьте html css

Comment: Что мне показывать то?)

Comment: мне надо сделать его четко right: 0; Но он дает скролл внизу из за большой  ширины картинки, можно как то это пофиксить или только обрезать ?